# Couldn't rename/move files across servers due to long File Names

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a `windows 2008 Server` and I am trying to move the files to another windows 2008 server that is going to work as an archive folder.

The problem I am having is the users have created files that are so buried in sub-folders, sometimes 10 to 15 folders deep, at each level some of the folder names can be 50+ characters long, that I get the error that the filename is to long and will not copy.

Comment: You should read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2891362)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the same operation from a windows commandprompt session.

Let me know whether this works.